# how to check Style Class is null, and if it is null how can we assign some style to it in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

i am using jquery for collapsible panel

i need to check it the style class is null, then i need to add some style .

```
styleClass="pr-icon-hide-table"

jQuery(btnId).toggleClass(styleClass); return false;
```

How can i check null for Style class!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(btnId).attr('style') == 'undefined'){
      // there is no in-line style
}

if(!$(btnId).hasClass(styleClass)){
      // Item doesn't have the class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass) to detect whether an element has the specific class.

```
if ($(btnId).hasClass(styleClass)) {
    // whatever; it has the class.
};
```

If you want to add a class depending on it, you should do;

```
if (!$(btnId).hasClass(styleClass)) {
    $(btnId).addClass('foo');
};
```

Bear in mind you might want to cache the result of `$(btnId)` so you don't perform the same operation twice;

```
var self = $(btnId);
if (!self.hasClass(styleClass)) {
    self.addClass('foo');
}
```

Terminology wise, you are not checking for `null` when you're checking if an element has a class or not. An element's classes are stored space-separated in it's `className` property, so technically you're checking whether the class name is contained within the `className` property (which is what `hasClass()` does [behind the scenes](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d511613d748a92af04a3f07943f34f9baadc4153/src/attributes.js#L146)).